# how to generate new information from old information file

Tags: php

How can I create new question from the previous question?

Right now, I have file name "edit.php" with button "create a new question" which will link to the page name "create_new.php"

when the user finished edited the question or information that they want, then they will click button "create new question" to generate new question into the database but also save the previous one as well

```
    <script>
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            document.forms["qform"].action = "edit_update.php";
            document.forms["qform"].submit();
        });
        $("#create_new").click(function(){
            document.forms["qform"].action = "create_new.php";
            document.forms["qform"].submit();
        });
   </script>
```

script will do two things:

1. if user click "submit", it will overwritten the current file into the database.
2. if user click "create_new", it will generate the new question from the previous question and save both file but the new file will assign as a new item inside the database.

I don't know which methods should I use for generating a new question and save into the database. If anyone have experienced this problem, please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Ur query is not clear can u define me in one line?

Comment: i don't undrestand your question but i think you want the new question to be show in the screen for that you give add colum status where you manage which is open or not on behave of your question inserted

Comment: I just want to generate new question from the old question by changing information inside the "edit.php" and save it as a new question

Comment: @AghaUmairAhmed yes something like that

Comment: then you add a new field in a table `status` and when u submitting new question make that status `1` and update all other question status to `0` and when you query the question give condition where status = 1